# I want to put a filter on a view that only shows the records from today

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, filter, modern-experience

I have a list with a date column and 3 other columns. I want to put a filter on a view that only shows the records from today.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add filtering in your list view.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list.
2. Click on **Switch view options** dropdown from the top.
3. Select **Edit current view**.

[image]

4. Add below filter in **Filter** section & click OK:

> Created is equal to `[Today]`.

[image]

If that doesn't work for, you can try this:

> Created is greater than `[Today]-1` And Created is less than `[Today]+1`

[image]

**Note**: This filter shows the items that are created today. You can select other date column instead of `Created` as per your requirements.

Comment: In the list in Sharepoint it works great but not in Microsoft Lists